Cannot connect remotely after updating vscode to 1.93
The error message when connecting remotely is as follows：
dea4f52cff30: running
Script executing under PID: 135648
Found existing installation at /home/baoyixiang/.vscode-server...
Starting VS Code CLI...
printenv:
    SHELL=/home/baoyixiang/bin/zsh
    LANGUAGE=zh_CN:zh
    PWD=/home/baoyixiang
    LOGNAME=baoyixiang
    XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
    MOTD_SHOWN=pam
    HOME=/home/baoyixiang
    LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
    SSH_CONNECTION=10.xxx.xxx.xx 64373 10.xxx.xx.xx 22
    XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
    USER=baoyixiang
    SHLVL=1
    XDG_SESSION_ID=9126
    XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/2000
    SSH_CLIENT=10.xxx.xxx.xx 64373 22
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/baoyixiang/bin
    DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/2000/bus
    OLDPWD=/home/baoyixiang
    _=/usr/bin/printenv
Removing old logfile at /home/baoyixiang/.vscode-server/.cli.4849ca9bdf9666755eb463db297b69e5385090e3.log
Spawned remote CLI: 135668
Waiting for server log...
Waiting for server log...
Exec server process not found
start_server:kill:25: kill 135668 failed: there is no such process
[2024-09-11 11:25:08] error could not parse `host`: invalid IP address syntax
dea4f52cff30: start
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==ubuntu==
arch==x86_64==
vscodeArch==x64==
bitness==64==
tmpDir==/run/user/2000==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
serverStartTime==90==
execServerToken==b20f7b52-5431-4db8-928b-ae4a1e607888==
platformDownloadPath==cli-alpine-x64==
dea4f52cff30: end

Configuration of ssh hosts:
Host 10.xxx.xx.xx
  HostName 10.xxx.xx.xx
  User baoyixiang

I deleted .vscode-server and let vscode regenerate, but it didn't work
I didn't do anything except update vscode, do I need to downgrade vscode?

downgrade to 1.92.2，it works

Seems detection of 'curl' is broken. I was also facing the same issue. For now: Switch remote extension to pre release version: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/10238
